# SQL subquery with aggregate value

Tags: sql, date, join, db2, max

Sorry for the vague title, I'm a little lost here. I have two simple aggregate SQL queries, but I struggle to combine them in a functional way (likely through a subquery) in IBM DB2. Main goal is to run COUNT function in INVOICES table - but with the starting date based on a subquery MAX aggregate result.

```
select count(a.invno), a.item from INVOICES a
where a.invdate > 20200101
group by a.item
```

But as noted, I don't want a.invdate to be fixed (20200101). I'd need to run MAX function in SERVICE table and use its result as the paramenter for a.invdate. Is there a reasonable way to do this?

```
select max(b.servdate), b.item from SERVICE b
where b.servtype = 1
group by b.item
```

So, looking to count invoices for each Item since the last service date (matching it's own parameters). Obviously, a.item = b.item here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you can `join`, or use a correlated subquery:

```
select count(i.invno), i.item 
from invoices i
where i.invdate > (
    select max(s.servdate) 
    from services s 
    where s.servtype = 1 and s.item = i.item
)
group by i.item
```

This should be an efficient approach, provided that you have an index on `services(item, servtype)`.

Alternatively, here is the `join` approach:

```
select count(i.invno), i.item 
from invoices i
inner join (
    select item, max(servdate) servdate
    from services
    where servtype = 1
    group by item
) s on s.item = i.item and s.invdate > s.servdate
group by i.item
```

Comment: I think you need a group by in the sub query too

Comment: @Hogan: no need to `group by`, this is a scalar subquery anyway.

Comment: oh I mean you want to use a join and then group by to get a faster result

Comment: @Hogan: in my experience, a correlated subquery with the right index is often the fastest approach. Still, I updated my answer with a solution that uses a `join`.

Comment: stranger things have happened

Comment: Sorry for the delay on my part. The first option worked fine, thank you! The only problem I have is if max(s.servdate) doesn't provide any value for this s.item - then it won't show this i.item at all in the query result. I'd prefer count(i.invno) to show value 0 then. I can solve this a workaround, but ideally this would work within the same query. Could CASE be used for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by item order by servdate desc) as seqnum
      from service s
      where s.servtype = 1
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

since no one else is showing what I think is the best way I will post it...

```
select count(i.invno), i.item 
from invoices i
join (
    select max(s.servdate) maxd, s.item
    from services s 
    where s.servtype = 1
    group by s.item
) as sub on sub.item = i.item and a.invdate > sub.maxd
group by i.item
```